# What are the reasons stopping me from correctly linking a static library in VS2010 to my .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to link a static library in VS2010 to my .dll and for some reason it won't resolve the required symbols. I've added the library like you would any library, but still no go. I'm also calling the symbols exactly as they should be, I'm copying someone else's implementation that works so they can't be wrong. Is it some kind of setting that I'm missing maybe? I've done a lib.exe /dumpall and everything looks to be in order. Very frustrating.

Comment: Is the library a C library? Do the function declarations from the library have `extern "C"` when compiled with a C++ compiler?

Comment: No, as far as I know it's a C++ lib that was compiled in VS2003 though. However, the original project that used it was a VS2003 project as well, but once I converted it to VS2010 it still worked fine.

Comment: This is where the original code is coming from. I'm trying to use their static link library. https://github.com/toots/microsoft-audio-watermarking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the link to the library, I see that the source are all C Source files, and none of the header have `extern "C"` for the function declarations.

That means if you include the header files into your project, the function declarations will have [mangled names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), names (symbols) that no longer matches the ones in the library.

Either you should declare the functions you use yourself with `extern "C"` or wrap the inclusion of the header files with `extern "C" { ... }`.